# Analysis and Translation of the song "Mientras duermen los niños" by Jose Luis Perales

Tags: traducción

I cannot find the translation of this song in English. It looks to be some sort of ballad with very deep [lyrics](http://www.quedeletras.com/letra-cancion-mientras-duermen-los-ninos-bajar-55728/disco-amaneciendo-en-ti/jose-luis-perales-mientras-duermen-los-ninos.html) but there are some elements of marching in the tone which doubts me. The what I can understand with Google Translate: there are parents and their children are sleeping. Then there are some sensual moments with happiness and pictoresque ideas to rain.

**Analytical brainteasers**

> 1. Ideas behind the song: imaginary and context? Similar songs?
> 2. Is the mother is going away but no idea how? For example, is the mother dead and the guy speaking alone and trying to get comfort for speaking alone? Other thing?
> 3. Or is the mother just going away like that and leaving everything behind? Can this be seen as a sociopolitical song or a liberation song
>      breaking the status-quo of home mothers?
> 4. What does the imaginery of switching off light mean in the point "turns off for me"? Suicide or just feeling bad?
> 5. Is the song a ballad or a very sad song where something bad has happened such as death of mother (perhaps just social mother but still
>      living?) or are they just happy that they have each other even though
>      some social tensions?
> 6. Or is all of this left open?

*P.s. I would like to have labels `translation`, `analysis`, `lyrics`, `music` and `culture`.*

Comment: Welcome to Spanish.SE! Unfortunately, your question is out of the scope of the site as it is not related to Spanish language usage. You could try asking in a Spanish speaking forum.

Comment: If you have a specific question about the meaning of a particularly difficult phrase or word in context while translating the song, that sort of question could be on-topic here. But asking for a translation of a block of text is expressly off-topic according to the [site scope](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Flimzy I think art such as music is one of the best way to understand `language usage` in all little details -- sad if not appropriate here because it reflects a lot things about culture and related things. Even though you don't know the language yet, it is very good way to learn it and investigate little things -- you can learn a lot by reading it and analysing it. I really think that musical analysis and particularly lyrics analysis of non-natives should be allowed because even a single comma can change meaning and it is very hard to understand certain songs without the cultural context.

Comment: @JoulSauron Because we are still in Beta, I see no reason to hold on new creative ideas such as arts in general. The trick is to make it more appropriate on this site -- which I am trying to do with the brainteasers. It requires good understanding of Spanish and some analytical skills to really answer this question. Taking a word out of a song misses so much of the context...

Comment: @hhh: Nobody is saying that translating songs, or analyzing them is not a good idea, or helpful for language study. But these activities are off-topic for the Stack Exchange network. This is a Q&A site; we invite your questions, and hope to provide answers. But we are not a translation service, and discussion topics, like analyzing a work, are not a good fit for the Q&A format.

Comment: Your edit, adding the "brain teasers" has changed the question from merely "off-topic" to also "too broad" and "primarily opinion based." I encourage you to read through our [help](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help) section, to better understand the scope and intent of this site.

Comment: Some of your "brain teaser" questions might make for good stand-alone questions on this site, if they boil down to an ambiguity or other missed meaning in the Spanish prose.

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember ever having heard this song before, and for what I can get your Google translation is way off.

> Vamos a romper
>   este silencio hoy,
>   es hora de hablar,
>   los niños duermen ya.
>   Me vas a contar
>   que está pasándote,
>   tus ojos no me miran
>   como antes.

Let's break this silent today.
It is time to talk; the kids are already in bed.
You are going to tell me what is happening to you.
Your eyes are not longer looking at me as before.

> Hoy,
>   antes de marcharte
>   piénsalo otra vez,
>   me preguntarán
>   por ti los niños

Today, before leaving, think it again,
the kids will ask for you

> Me dirán:
>   ¿dónde se fue, papá?
>   y cada noche soñaran,
>   con ese cuento
>   que no han de escuchar.
>   No debes irte, no.

They will say to me: where she went, dad?
And every night they will dream
with this story they shall not listen to.
You must not go, no.

> Y yo
>   que voy a hacer sin ti,
>   cuando se muera la tarde
>   y se me apague el sol.
>   Si tu sillón, vacío ya estará.
>   Esas flores que sembraste
>   se marchitarán
>   y nadie las cuidará
>   mejor que tú.

And me, what am I do without you,
when the afternoon fades and the sun turns off for me.
If your armchair already be empty.
These flowers you planted will fade
and nobody is going to take care of them better than you.

Comment: +1 thank you! I moved brainteasers to the question, there are still points that this song gets me thinking. I am not yet sure of the meaning and the goal of this song, just beautiful song perhaps, dunno.